# How can i creat Objects in one class and save them in array in another class?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, abstract

for my exams in Java in a couple of weeks i go trough any old exams i get my fingers on. But there is one task i can't get my head arround. I need a solution for this.

You should creat a abstract Class called Plant(just with Attributes for height and weight). 
There are three Sub Classes (Tomato, Bellpeper and Onions)

Then you need a Class called Greenhouse, in this Greenhouse is room for Excactly 30 Plants in total. It dosent matter what kind of Plants.

If you want to store more then 30 Plants then it should drop a Exception.

i know i need:

- a Final attribute for the 30 plants.
- Array.Add to get the Objects in my Array.
- and a Method that calculated 30 - the length of my Array List.

but i dont know how to use this. There a lot of Tutorials for stuff like this in the same class but not from another class.

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings from Germany

Comment: Can you post the code you have attempted?   There many different ways to approach this problem, and it more beneficial to fix _your_ solution rather than create the entire solution for you.  It is not very clear what your question exactly is either.

Comment: Greeting from India -> please share your code here whatever you have tried

Answer (score 1):

You just need a method in your Greenhouse class. for example

```
public void addPlant(Plant p) throws Exception //Placeholder exception
```

Where you take the Plant as an argument, check if you have room in the Greenhouse arraylist, and either add it, or throw the exception. It doesn't matter which class creates the Plant, it will be passed to the Greenhouse class via this method.